# How to generate a git diff (patch) of a mode change to a binary file?

Tags: git, git-diff

I've got a git repo that contains a few binary files. I've staged a chmod 755 to one of the binary files and I want to generate a diff of this mode change that can be applied on another machine with git-apply. I'm using:

```
git diff --no-color --no-ext-diff --binary --cached 560d4ad7ca02fe3cb2403da89fadae0c27fbbe73
```

This works just fine for non-binary mode changes, and even for binary mode changes as long as the binary itself has also changed. But if only the mode on the binary file has changed, then then the above diff is empty.

I can get an output from git diff if I use:

```
git diff --no-color --no-ext-diff --binary --cached --raw 560d4ad7ca02fe3cb2403da89fadae0c27fbbe73
```

Unfortunately, the output of the above command cannot be fed into git apply:

```
:100644 100755 e944703... e944703... M  asbserver
```

Any ideas? It seems strange to me that the diff works if there is both a change to the contents of the binary file as well as a mode change?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ chmod +x foo
$ git diff
diff --git a/foo b/foo
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

I get a diff which seems usable. Maybe your problem is more on the apply side. How are you applying your patch? Are you using the [--apply switch](http://gitmanual.org/git-apply.html)? (it can be needed in some cases, this depends on your full command).

Edit following the comment: With a binary file I get:

```
$ chmod +x favicon.ico
$ git diff
diff --git a/assets/favicon.ico b/assets/favicon.ico
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

And favicon.ico is correctly guessed as binary:

```
$ git show f948cbeb33532d0803a9c | grep favicon
diff --git a/assets/favicon.ico b/assets/favicon.ico
Binary files /dev/null and b/assets/favicon.ico differ
```

Comment: The 'foo' file you've created doesn't appear to be a binary file. This works fine for non-binary files. Try it with a binary file. The problem isn't on the apply side, the problem is that 'git diff' gives 0 output.

Comment: Updated to have the diff against a binary file. Do you have some things in your project .git/config which could affect the way the diff command run?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it. The only settings are filemode=true and repositoryformatversion=0. Are you sure that git is treating your ico file as a binary file? Which OS are you on?

Comment: Added a grep of the commit diff when adding the favicon.ico file. I am on Linux.

Comment: Interesting. That's really strange. I've tried this on a variety of repositories and binaries and always get the same thing: git diff doesn't show any output if I only change the file mode, but it does show the file mode change if I also modify the contents of the binary. Do you have anything special in your git config?

Comment: Nothing at all. My git version is 1.7.4.1.